# How to print string format which is entered from Console.Readline() aa1234aa, in this format aa-1234-aa?

Tags: c#

Given an input string such as "KK1234KK" how can I have it print it out with additional formatting: "KK-1234-KK"? In code I had hoped to be able to do something like this:

```
string LicensePlate = "KK1234KK";

Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Custom: {0:##-####-##}", LicensePlate));
```

Comment: Hint: `String.Format` only works with number and date data types. To do this sort of thing, you might want to look into using a Regex.

Comment: What is the output you are expecting from that "custom format"?

Comment: I want to insert kk1234kk in Console.ReadLine(), but i want it to be printed in this format: kk-1234-kk. To be added "-" between letters and numbers.

Comment: Reopened since as the comments say `String.Format` will not solve this problem.

Comment: @Sym_j: I've edited your question to add some text explanation. I hope you are happy with the changes I've made. If you aren't feel free to rollback or further edit it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using regex expression to get it in this format. Here I'm looking for the number and adding "-" on both sides.

```
        string LicensePlate = "KK1234KK";
        Regex regex = new Regex(@"\d+");
        Match match = regex.Match(LicensePlate);
        string output = Regex.Replace(LicensePlate, @"\d+","-"+match.Value+"-");
```